# Applescript VPN + document.readyState problems

Tags: macos, google-chrome, vpn, applescript

I'm trying to create an Applescript App to connect to my University's VPN Network. The process is done usually through connecting to a specific WiFi network then connecting to the VPN itself (via the built in VPN management on OSX) then opening a Login Webpage and logging in then closing said Webpage.

My code is as follows:

```
set vpn_name to "'VPN NAME'"
set pageLoaded to false

tell application "System Events"
    set rc to do shell script "scutil --nc status " & vpn_name
    if rc starts with "Connected" then
        do shell script "scutil --nc stop " & vpn_name
    else
        do shell script "scutil --nc start " & vpn_name
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            open location "HTTPS://LOGIN.COM"
            repeat
                if (execute javascript "document.readyState") is "completed" then set pageLoaded to true
            end repeat
            display dialog pageLoaded
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

I've granted Keychain Access for the VPN to connect automatically without needing my Username and Password each time and have the VPN connection part of the Script working fine (connecting and disconnecting on each run). I am however having trouble getting the Login Webpage to load and a document.readyState to wait for the webpage to load before it keys Enter to use the saved Login details.

Any/all help or direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

```
set pageLoaded to false
repeat until (pageLoaded = true)
    if (execute javascript "document.readyState") is "completed" 
        set pageLoaded to true
        exit repeat
    end if
    else delay 1
end repeat
```

I can't test & I don't know javascript, so it's just a guess